# React Native source maps (and breakpoints) in Chrome not matching

Tags: react-native

Is anyone having the issue where when they add breakpoints in the Sources tab they can't add them to most lines, and when you do, the debugger breaks on another line.

The source maps don't seem to be matching up properly. I'm using my actual device. Not sure if that's an issue. Are there any additional setup requirements for debugging in chrome other than what is mentioned here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

???

Comment: Yes, in my case source code was paused within an if statement even I knew the condition was false for that case, I think this is a case related with the google chrome core when it try to match the minified file with the source code.

Comment: This is strange. Question asked 7 years ago and I am facing this issue today. Did you solved that if you remember? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77398277/breakpoints-not-being-hit-correctly-in-expo

Answer (score 0):

(If you use Expo) For a quick workaround you can put `debugger` statement(s) into the code to force the DevTools(or VScode Expo Tools) to pause the execution at right point.

An example:

[image]

Related link: https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/tools/#pausing-on-breakpoints

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).